# PHP validation only number and number with comma

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make validation number with format x or x.xx (4 or 4.21). The format I managed to use regex for the x (single digit) is `\ b \ d \ b`.
For x.xx format (two decimal places) I haven't found the regex pattern yet

```
$tes = 1;
if(!preg_match('\b\d\b', $tes)){
    echo 'right format';
 }else{
    echo 'not right';
 }
```

Comment: in don't know patrent regex to validate format x.xx

Comment: `'~^\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?$~'`, see https://regex101.com/r/GYhamN/1

Comment: why are you using regex to validate a number in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> For x.xx format (two decimal places)

If I understand correctly, you want to take exactly one number before point and two numbers after point.
So, I suggest the following regex.

```
^\d(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

Details:

- `^\d`: always start with number
- `(?:\.\d{2})`: this is optional. After the first number, we have exactly .xx
- `?$`: we take as many cases as possible

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYhamN/3)